# localhost redirects to one of local websites

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I added to C:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1 mywebiste
```

and in httpd-vhosts.conf added:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/mywebiste"
    ServerName mywebsite
    ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/access.log" common

    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/mywebiste">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Multiviews
        Options -Indexes
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        #RedirectMatch ^/$ / index.php

        Options +FollowSymLinks
        IndexIgnore */*
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule . index.php
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And now when I want to add new website to hosts file and httpd-vhosts.conf it renders 'mywebsite' and I cant access that website, even if I delete my virtualhost in httpd-vhosts.conf and remove my entry from hosts file it still renders 'mywebsite'. What should I do to fix this, I have no clue?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

Prior to any `<VirtualHost...>` lines

See [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost)

Comment: But why then if I delete all my costum settings and write in search bar 'localhost/mynewwebsite' it redirects to 'localhost/mywebiste'? I even cant just write in 'localhost' it just redirects me to 'localhost/website'.

Comment: @Townsheriff Did you try `http://mynewwebsite`?  That is what virtual hosts are about (not virtual directories, like `http://localhost/myvirtualdirectory`)

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind, you have to restart the apache to apply new settings :) sorry. Btw it doesnt work at all wit NamevirtualHost.